# What does this OpenProcessToken do when processHandle = -1?

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, x86

I understand what this does but what does it mean ProcessHandle is set to -1 as follow?

```
.text:004011D2 83 EC 20             sub     esp, 20h
.text:004011D5 8D 04 24             lea     eax, [esp+20h+TokenHandle]
.text:004011D8 50                   push    eax          ; TokenHandle
.text:004011D9 6A 28                push    28h          ; DesiredAccess
.text:004011DB 6A FF                push    0FFFFFFFFh   ; ProcessHandle
.text:004011DD E8 96 04 00 00       call    OpenProcessToken
```

Answer (score 4):

The -1 process handle is a handle to the current process. It's better to call [`GetCurrentProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683179.aspx) instead, as recommended on MSDN:

> Retrieves a pseudo handle for the current process.
>   ...
>   A pseudo handle is a special constant, currently **(HANDLE)-1**, that is interpreted as the current process handle. For compatibility with future operating systems, it is best to call GetCurrentProcess instead of hard-coding this constant value.